Unity cloud .pdb symbol upload failed
I upload pdb symbol file to unity cloud.
Symbols are built with source code made in c++ and are referenced by Unity.
but it's failed and print "system error".
error
I can't find why it is failed.
please help me...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
